# Installing ROS in a conda environment

Tags: ros

I'm planning to setup ROS and it's dependencies in a conda environment (similar to virtualenv). I've read a few posts where they state it's not going to be simple. Did any of you guys do it ? If you did, can you please share the steps ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer from a Google search, just for your information in 2021 installing ROS in conda should be much straightforward, see the following links:

- https://medium.com/robostack/cross-platform-conda-packages-for-ros-fa1974fd1de3
- https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-noetic